# How to set min/max date add default and disable future/pass date for admin grid massaction

Tags: php, magento, datetime

Can I set min / max (today) on `massaction` date on custom admin grid and disable to click date on future/pass and set now to default value if user don't want to select?

My code now is as follows:

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('setdate', array(
    'label' => $this->__('Set Date'),
    'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massSetdate', array('' => '')), 
    'confirm' => $this->__('Are you sure?'),
    'additional' => array(
        'setmaxdate' => array(
            'name'     => 'setmaxdate',
            'time'     => true,
            'input'    => 'datetime',
            'type'     => 'datetime',
            'class'    => 'required-entry',
            'label'    => Mage::helper('setcustomdate')->__('Set Max Date'),
            //'gmtoffset' => true,
            'image'    => '/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif',
            'format'   => 'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss'
        )
    )
));
```